# Combination generator in Java - 2nd iteration

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics, iterator

I have refactored the [previous combination generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118893/combination-generator-in-java), and now it is an iterator returning combinations as lists. It hides larger constant factors as the previous version, yet it is really easy to use:

```
for (List<String> combination : new CombinationIterable<>(allStrings)) {
    System.out.println(combination);
}
```

**`CombinationIterable.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class CombinationIterable<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {

    private final List<T> allElements;

    public CombinationIterable(List<T> allElements) {
        this.allElements = new ArrayList<>(allElements);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
        return new CombinationIterator<>(allElements);
    }

    private static final class CombinationIterator<T> 
    implements Iterator<List<T>> {

        private final List<T> allElements;
        private final int[] indices;
        private List<T> nextCombination;
        private int currentCombinationSize;

        CombinationIterator(List<T> allElements) {
            this.allElements = new ArrayList<>(allElements);
            this.indices = new int[allElements.size()];

            if (!allElements.isEmpty()) {
                // Create the first combination.
                currentCombinationSize = 1;
                nextCombination = new ArrayList<>(1);
                nextCombination.add(allElements.get(0));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextCombination != null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<T> next() {
            if (nextCombination == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No combinations left.");
            }

            List<T> combination = nextCombination;
            generateNextCombination();
            return combination;
        }

        private void loadCombination() {
            List<T> combination = new ArrayList<>(currentCombinationSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < currentCombinationSize; ++i) {
                combination.add(allElements.get(indices[i]));
            }

            this.nextCombination = combination;
        }

        private void generateNextCombination() {
            if (indices[currentCombinationSize - 1] < indices.length - 1) {
                indices[currentCombinationSize - 1]++;
                loadCombination();
                return;
            }

            for (int i = currentCombinationSize - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (indices[i] < indices[i + 1] - 1) {
                    indices[i]++;

                    for (int j = i + 1; j < currentCombinationSize; ++j) {
                        indices[j] = indices[j - 1] + 1;
                    }

                    loadCombination();
                    return;
                }
            }

            ++currentCombinationSize;

            if (currentCombinationSize > indices.length) {
                this.nextCombination = null;
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < currentCombinationSize; ++i) {
                indices[i] = i;
            }

            loadCombination();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> all = new ArrayList<>();

        all.add("A");
        all.add("B");
        all.add("C");
        all.add("D");
        all.add("E");

        int row = 1;

        for (List<String> combination : new CombinationIterable<>(all))  {
            System.out.printf("%2d: %s\n", row++, combination);
        }
    }
}
```

**`CombinationIterableTest.java:`**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class CombinationIterableTest {

    private CombinationIterable generator;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<String> all = new ArrayList<>();

        all.add("A");
        all.add("B");
        all.add("C");
        all.add("D");
        all.add("E");

        for (int i = 1; i <= all.size(); ++i) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                list.add(all.get(j));
            }

            int combinations = pow2(i) - 1;
            int count = 0;

            for (List<String> combination : new CombinationIterable<>(list)) {
                ++count;
            }

            assertEquals(combinations, count);
        }
    }

    private static int pow2(int exp) {
        return 1 << exp;
    }
}
```

Is there anything to improve?

Comment: In theory, you could just use a single loop for 0 to 2^all.size() and use bitand'ing to choose which elements to include. You could also create this as array of strings, then sort them and split them back into sets.

Comment: I don't understand what bitand'ing you are talking about; please consider providing an answer.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#Binary_String is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only minor remarks - not so much related to the code itself, but rather to the concepts:

---

In [your previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118893/combination-generator-in-java), you emphasized that the combinations should be returned in **lexicographic** order. From my understanding, this is not the case: The output is

```
 1: [A]
 2: [B]
 3: [C]
 4: [D]
 5: [E]
 6: [A, B]
 7: [A, C]
 8: [A, D]
 9: [A, E]
...
```

Imagining these as "words in a dictionary" (in line with the [Wikipedia page about lexicographical_order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)), "AB" would come before "B" - but maybe this is just a misinterpretation on my side, and you are considering the words to be "filled with some character that comes before 'A'" at the beginning, as in

```
____A
____B
____C
...
___AB
___AC
...
_ABCD
_ABCE
...
ABCDE
```

---

The word "Combination" usually has a predefined meaning that differs from how you use it: A [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) is usually a selection of a *certain number of elements* from a given set. (Differentiated between "combinations with repetition" and "combinations without repetition").

What you are computing there are actually the elements of the [Power Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the given list (which usually also involves the empty list - but this is just a detail).

This is also what the comments referred to: When looking closely at the elements of the power set, you'll see a resemblance of these elements and the bit patterns of the binary representations of numbers:

```
               EDCBA   Result:
0   binary:    00000   {     }
1   binary:    00001   {    A}
2   binary:    00010   {   B }
3   binary:    00011   {   BA}
...
9   binary:    01001   { D  A}
...
31  binary:    11111   {EDCBA}
```

This can be imagined as "taking the elements into the result when the binary representation of the corresponding number has a '1' at the respective position".

Unfortunately, the order would then be different from your current one, so this may not be applicable here.

---

In terms of API design, there is probably not much more to say: The implementation as an `Iterable` makes it very easy to use it, as there are only two (relevant) public methods with well-known semantics, and, as far as I can see, they are implemented properly. One could consider different, minor restructurings of the private parts, but none that would objectively be "better" than the current solution.

---

<sub>A side note: A while ago I created some similar classes at https://github.com/javagl/Combinatorics . They are also implemented as `Iterable`s, including a `CombinationIterable`, but as mentioned above, this computes *combinations* - in contrast to the [`PowerSetIterable`](https://github.com/javagl/Combinatorics/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/utils/math/combinatorics/PowerSetIterable.java#L114), which computes the power set that you actually seem to be looking for - it contains a few words about the implementation using the binary number representations.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

On their own, your *combinatorics Iterables* look pretty generic.

- Given that they are `Iterable`s rather than `List`s or `Collection`s, one consideration would be instantiation with an `Iterable`.

Another thing to ponder would be the name [*itertools*](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).
Even with "the basic three", this seems to call for common base classes - I gave it a try, without proper attention to other concerns. (One thing I'm never quite comfortable with is visibility: `protected` exposes quite a lot.) I didn't succeed in integrating Partitions without a second type parameter:

```
/** several classes for combinatorics */
abstract class Combinics {
 /** Instantiated with a List of elements of type {@code E}, for
  *  one type of aggregation of elements represented as {@code
  *  List<I>} support iteration through all these aggregations.
  * Elements at different positions are considered different. */
    static abstract class Iterable<E, I>
        implements java.lang.Iterable<List<I>> {

        protected final /*E*/Object[] allElements;

        /*final*/ int param;

        public Iterable(List<E> allElements) {
            final int count = allElements.size();
            if (0 == count)
                this.allElements = null;
            else {
            //  E first = allElements.get(0);
                this.allElements = allElements.toArray(
            // off: allElements need not be of uniform type
            //      (E[]) Array.newInstance(first.getClass(), count)
                    );
            }
        }
    }
 /** Instantiated with a List of elements of type {@code E}, for
  *  one type of aggregation of elements represented as {@code
  *  List<I>} support iteration through all these aggregations.
  * Elements at different positions are considered different. */
    static abstract class Iterator<E, I> 
        implements java.util.Iterator<List<I>> {


        final /*E*/Object[] allElements;
        final int[] indices;
    // ArrayList for extended interface - YAGNI?
        ArrayList<I> next;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E get(int index) {
            return (E) allElements[index];
        }

        Iterator(List<? extends E> allElements) {
            this(allElements, allElements.size());
        }

        Iterator(List<? extends E> allElements, int count) {
            indices = new int[count];
            if (0 == count)
                this.allElements = null;
            else {
                E first = allElements.get(0);
                this.allElements = allElements.toArray(
                // slightly off: allElement need not be of uniform type
                    (E[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
                        first.getClass(), count)
                    );
            }
        }

        Iterator(Object[] allElements, int count) {
            indices = new int[count];
            this.allElements = allElements;
        }
        protected int size() { return indices.length; }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return next != null;
        }
    /** for messages and more */// cache? nah...
        protected String singular() {
            String className = getClass().getName();
            int
                lastDot = className.lastIndexOf('.')+1,
                lastIter = className.indexOf("Iter", lastDot);
            if (0 <= ".$".indexOf(className.charAt(lastIter-1)))
                lastIter -= 1;
            return className.substring(lastDot,
                lastIter).toLowerCase();
        }
    /** for messages and more */
        protected String plural() { return singular() + 's'; }

        @Override
        public List<I> next() {
            if (next == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException(
                    "No " + plural() + " left.");
            }

            List<I> current = next;
            generateNext();
            return current;
        }
    /** Generates and keeps the next aggregation. */
        abstract void generateNext();
    /** non-public in java.util.Arrays */
        protected static void swap(int[] array, int a, int b) {
            int tmp = array[a];
            array[a] = array[b];
            array[b] = tmp;
        }
    }

 /** Instantiated with a List of elements of type {@code E},
  * for combinations of elements represented as {@code List<E>}
  * support iteration through all these combinations.
  * Elements at different positions are considered different. */
    static abstract class IterElements<T> extends Iterator<T, T> {
        IterElements(List<T> allElements) { super(allElements); }
        IterElements(List<T> allElements, int count) {
            super(allElements, count);
        }
        IterElements(Object[] allElements, int count) {
            super(allElements, count);
        }

        protected void load() {
            next = new ArrayList<>(size());

            for (int i = 0; i < size() ; ++i) {
                next.add(get(indices[i]));
            }
        }
    }

    static void
    demo(int count, Function<List<?>, Iterable<?, ?>> generator) {
        List<String> all = new ArrayList<>(count);
        for (char c = 'A', end = (char) ('A' + count) ; c < end ; c++)
            all.add(String.valueOf(c));

        int row = 1;

        for (List<String> elements : (Iterable<String, String>)
                generator.apply(all))  {
            System.out.printf("%2d: %s\n", row++, elements);
        }
    }
}

/** Instantiated with a List of elements of type {@code E},
 * for combinations of elements represented as {@code List<E>}
 * support iteration through all these combinations.
 * Elements at different positions are considered different. */
public class Combination<E> extends Combinics.Iterable<E, E> {

    public Combination(List<E> allElements, int nElements) {
        super(allElements);
        param = nElements;
    }
    public Combination(List<E> allElements) { this(allElements, -1); }

    @Override
    public java.util.Iterator<List<E>> iterator() {
        return param < 0 ? new Iterator<E>(allElements)
            : new Iterator<E>(allElements, param);
    }
 /** Instantiated with a List of elements of type {@code E},
  * for combinations of elements represented as {@code List<E>}
  * support iteration through all these combinations.
  * Elements at different positions are considered different. */
    static class Iterator<E> extends Combinics.IterElements<E> {
        int currentSize;
        Iterator(List<E> allElements) {
            this(allElements, 1, allElements.size());
        }
        Iterator(List<E> allElements, int count) {
            this(allElements, count, count);
        }
        Iterator(List<E> allElements, int start, int end) {
            super(allElements, end);
            init(start);
        }
        void init(int start) {
            if (0 != indices.length) {
                // Create the first combination.
                currentSize = start;
                next = new ArrayList<>(currentSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; ++i)
                    indices[i] = i;
                load();
            }
        }
        Iterator(Object... allElements) {
            this(allElements, 1, allElements.length);
        }
        Iterator(Object[] allElements, int param) {
            this(allElements, param, param);
        }
        Iterator(Object[] allElements, int start, int end) {
            super(allElements, end);
            init(start);
        }
//      @Override
//      protected String singular() { return "combination"; }

        @Override
        protected int size() { return currentSize; }

        @Override
        void generateNext() {
            next = new ArrayList<E>(next); // late?
            if (indices[currentSize - 1] < allElements.length - 1) {
                indices[currentSize - 1]++;
                next.set(currentSize - 1, get(indices[currentSize-1]));
                return;
            }

            for (int i = currentSize - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (indices[i] < indices[i + 1] - 1) {
                    indices[i]++;

                    for (int j = i + 1; j < currentSize; ++j) {
                        indices[j] = indices[j - 1] + 1;
                    }

                    load();
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (indices.length < ++currentSize) {
                next = null;
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; ++i) {
                indices[i] = i;
            }

            load();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Combinics.demo(5, (all) -> new Combination<>(all));
        Iterator<String> combinations =
            new Combination.Iterator<String>(
                Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 3);
    // provoke Exception
        for (List<String> combi ;
             null != (combi = combinations.next()) ; ) {
            System.out.println(combi);
        }
    }
}



public class PartitionIterable<E>
    extends Combinics.Iterable<E, List<E>> {

    private final int blocks;

    public PartitionIterable(List<E> allElements, int blocks) {
        super(allElements);
        checkNumberOfBlocks(blocks, allElements.size());
        this.blocks = blocks;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<List<E>>> iterator() {
        return new PartitionIterator<>(allElements, blocks);
    }

    private void
    checkNumberOfBlocks(int blocks, int numberOfElements) {
        if (blocks < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The number of blocks should be at least 1, received: "
                + blocks);
        }

        if (blocks > numberOfElements) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The number of blocks should be at most "
                + numberOfElements + ", received: " + blocks);
        }   
    }

    private static class PartitionIterator<E> 
        extends Combinics.Iterator<E, List<E>> {

        private final int blocks;

        private final int[] s;
        private final int[] m;
        private final int n;

        PartitionIterator(List<E> allElements, int blocks) {
            super(allElements);
            this.blocks = blocks;
            this.n = allElements.size();

            s = indices;//new int[n];
            m = new int[n];

            if (n != 0) {
                for (int i = n - blocks + 1; i < n; ++i) {
                    s[i] = m[i] = i - n + blocks;
                }

                loadPartition();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected String singular() { return "partition"; }

        private void loadPartition() {
            next = new ArrayList<>(blocks);

            for (int i = 0; i < blocks; ++i) {
                next.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                next.get(s[i]).add(allElements.get(i));
            }
        }

        @Override
        void generateNext() {
            for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; --i) {
                if (s[i] < blocks - 1 && s[i] <= m[i - 1]) {
                    s[i]++;
                    m[i] = Math.max(m[i], s[i]);

                    int limit = n - blocks + m[i] + 1;
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < limit; ++j) {
                        s[j] = 0;
                        m[j] = m[i];
                    }

                    for (int j = limit; j < n; ++j) {
                        s[j] = m[j] = blocks - n + j;
                    }

                    loadPartition();
                    return;
                }
            }

            next = null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
        int row = 1;

        for (int blocks = 1; blocks <= list.size(); ++blocks) {
            for (List<List<String>> partition : 
                    new PartitionIterable<>(list, blocks)) {
                System.out.printf("%2d: %s\n", row++, partition);
            }
        }
    }
}

class PermutationIterable<T>
    extends Combinics.Iterable<T, T> {

    public PermutationIterable(List<T> allElements) {
        super(allElements);
    }

    @Override
    public java.util.Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<>(allElements);
    }

    private static final class Iterator<T>
        extends Combinics.IterElements<T> {

        Iterator(List<T> allElements) {
            super(allElements);
            if (allElements.isEmpty())
                next = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i) {
                indices[i] = i;
            }

            next = new ArrayList<>(allElements);
        }
//        @Override
//        protected String singular() { return "permutation"; }

        void generateNext() {
            int i = indices.length - 2;

            while (i >= 0 && indices[i] > indices[i + 1]) {
                --i;
            }

            if (i == -1) {
                // No more new permutations.
                next = null;
                return;
            }

            int j = i + 1;
            int min = indices[j];
            int minIndex = j;

            while (j < indices.length) {
                if (indices[i] < indices[j] && indices[j] < min) {
                    min = indices[j];
                    minIndex = j;
                }

                ++j;
            }

            swap(indices, i, minIndex);

            ++i;
            j = indices.length - 1;

            while (i < j) {
                swap(indices, i++, j--);
            }

            load();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        Combinics.main(4,
            (alphabet) -> new PermutationIterable<>(alphabet));
    }
}
```

Comment: ran out of time: numerical parameter used with python's itertools combinations is there, toDo: permutations, partitions,…